# get values from xml and transfering to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml, loops

I need some help.
I must to get the values from xml (i try by simplexml, but it doesn't work).
I have something like this:

```
<param name="country" type="text">Germany</param>
<param name="city" type="text">Munchen</param>
```

and I wanna to entered this values to my MySQL like

```
INSTERT INTO localization SET country='Germany', city='Munchen'
```

this must be done in loop, because I have many values
Somebody knows how it can work? Thanks!

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="country" type="hidden" value="germany">
<input name="city" type="hidden" value="Munchen">
```

if you wanna make a loop of a value you should use php and add sessions or post tags to make loop value that the member or user choose.